# How to fix bad parameters to mail() error in OpenCart?

Tags: php, paypal, opencart

I'm having a problem with OpenCart in that when 'Confirm Order' is pressed when checking out with PayPal Pro using a debit/credit card, the 'please wait' message appears then disappears without progress to the confirmation page. The emails get sent to the customer and the owner, the money is paid, and yet to get to the confirmation page you have to press 'Confirm Order' once again. This sends the money to PayPal again but no extra emails get sent and a second order doesn't appear in OpenCart records.

On the first click the following error message is generated three times:

```
PHP Warning:  mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Bad parameters to mail() function, mail not sent. in /.../store/system/library/mail.php on line 148
```

However, the email does actually get sent. On the second click, no errors are generated.

I've checked the email settings over and they all seem to be correct (I've tried both `info@domain.com` and `-finfo@domain.com` in the Mail Parameters box) and nothing changes. I'm using the mail option not SMTP.

The host is GoDaddy, which I'm aware is sometimes a bit funny with emails. I tried following the code through in PHP but I couldn't find where the parameters variable is actually set apart from that I think it gets it from the settings in the OpenCart admin.

I tried removing the parameters option from the mail() function in mail.php and the checkout works on the first click but the mails aren't sent at all, so I'm pretty sure fixing the error will fix the checkout problem, I'm just not sure what to try next.

Edit:

I've been doing some experimenting with the line that sends the email. OpenCart originally has it set as:

```
mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header, $this->parameter);
```

To make sure mail was actually working like this, I changed it to:

```
mail('myaddress@email.com', 'Test', 'Hello', 'From: info@domain.com', '-finfo@domain.com');
```

That worked. I clicked 'Confirm order' and it worked like it's supposed to. I then tried various combinations of removing the variables and replacing them with the details from my test. First I added back in $this->parameter thinking it was the most likely culprit but that worked fine. I continued doing this with the other variables, but it failed every single time.

Comment: I would like to see cofigurations sendmail_from and sendmail_path from your `phpinfo()`

Comment: Are you sure that you can send mails (any other mail) from GoDaddy by `mail`? Usually on shared hostings you need to use your SMTP for that...

Comment: @shadyx "However, the email does actually get sent.", although it is strange that an error message appears even when the email sends...

Comment: In your store/system/library/mail.php on line 148, do a var_dump of the variables used in the mail() function, to see if they all actually contain a value. A sloppy fix can be to add @ before the mail function, thus deprecating any error messages. Not advicable though. First, do the var_dump() of all variables passed to mail to check them.

Comment: @Ole Haugset Unfortunately nothing showed up when I tried the var_dump. Probably something to do with the way OpenCart works. I tried the sloppy fix too, but it did nothing. I still get the error message and I still get the problem.

Comment: Could you post here your code how the mail method is invoked and it's variables declared and/or set? Also let us now if you have installed any extensions (that could interfere with this mail sending). At which point - when adding back the previous arguments from your edit - it started to give the error message again? There should be one exact point - if you go back to your own values, then start returning previous variables one at a time and trying - suddenly at one point you got the error. The last returned variable should be inspected then.

Comment: Can you hook into the order complete event? I had much better success setting up PHPMailer to handle my emails instead of relying on Mail() on GoDaddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shop owner had added some extra email addresses for orders to be sent to. These email addresses should've been in the format `address1@email.com,address2.email.com`, etc.

Instead, there was a space after the comma and this was completely throwing OpenCart. There should probably be some sort of fix added to OpenCart to ignore spaces in the email field, but for now, it's all working.